# How to stream your images/files with VLC?

Tags: c#, .net, streaming, vlc, libvlc

So I know there are lot of wrappers of libVLC.dll . But I just do not know what one is ready to do what I need...

What I need is simple...

- in my C# program I create some bitmap (once or twice per second)...
- I now want to stream bitmaps live as video (in some format VLC can to offer me) to some http:localhost:port/ using VLC...

How to do that?

Comment: BTW, you don't need to put "(C# .Net)" in the title since you've got it in the tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use following code to stream  a image.

```
cd "C:\program files\videolan\vlc" 
vlc -I dummy fake:// --fake-file c:\1.jpg -vvv --sout #transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=1024,scale=1}:duplicate{dst=std{access=udp,mux=ts,dst=localhost:1234}}
```

Comment: Hello! I try your example on my Windows 10 PC and VLC 3.0.3 and I have an error... May be dummy or fake does not support in this version of VLC?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the NativeLibVlc.cs file available at VLC site.

To stream the bitmap file use following code

```
   vlc.AddTarget("fake://", new string[] {":no-overlay", ":input-repeat=-1", 
                        ":vout-filter=adjust", ":fake-file=" + fileName.Trim(), ":fake-fps=1",
                        ":brightness="+50, ":fake-caching=100"} , ref playListId);

 vlc.Play(playListId);
```

To stream webcam over UPD on port 1234 use    following code

```
cd "C:\program files\videolan\vlc"
vlc.exe -vvv --dshow-vdev="Logitech QuickCam Express / Go" dshow:// --sout #transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=1024,scale=1}:duplicate{dst=std{access=udp,mux=ts,dst=localhost:1234}}
```

To stream a video on port 1234 use following code

```
cd "C:\program files\videolan\vlc" 
vlc.exe -vvv C:\filename.wmv --repeat --sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=1024,scale=1}:duplicate{dst=std{access=udp,mux=ts,dst=localhost:1234}}
```

To stream a image on localhost port 1234 use following code

```
cd "C:\program files\videolan\vlc" 
vlc -I dummy fake:// --fake-file c:\1.jpg -vvv --sout #transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=1024,scale=1}:duplicate{dst=std{access=udp,mux=ts,dst=localhost:1234}}
```

Comment: and  new string[] here is r,g,b string or what?

Comment: Its parameters(options) to VLC player to play the image.
fake:// specifies that the image is going to be played instead of a video/ audio file.

Comment: And will I be able to vach this images stream as video useing VLC for example? If yes - how ? To what url I should go using normal VLC player to play this stream?

Comment: @Ole : For image streaming  you need to check VLC forum. The VLC experts will definitely help you out in this.

Comment: So... Where do I put my RGB values? or I always shousd save data to file before playing? And in my Q I asked about live streaming to some local port, could you please add sample code about this to your answer?

Comment: @Ole : I would suggest you should save the file before playing. You need to check options to set RGB.

I have added code of batch file to stream the video /Image.

Comment: Grate!) all 3 parts... But the Q was "I now want to stream bitmaps live as video (in some format VLC can to offer me) to some http:localhost:port/ using VLC..." so Is there a way to do SUCH thing using suggested by you NativeLibVlc? Is it any how possible to integrate thouse commands into it?

Comment: Well  check for the last one. It will stream a image on localhost port 1234.

You can create batch file to play this or need to call VLC with the provided parameters.