# Generating video from a sequence of images in C#

Tags: c#, windows, image, video, ffmpeg

I have a task of generating video from a sequence of images in my app and while searching for that i found out that FFMPEG is able to do that.Can anyone provide me any tutorial or link which can guide me in right direction.I am a newbiew in this so please help appropriately guys.
Will appreciate any sort of help

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Comment: Check if [this][1] helps. You cans create batch file to play image.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738228/how-to-stream-your-images-files-with-vlc/2865939#2865939

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library
http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html -> search for For creating a video from many images:

All the links  are from [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870103/create-a-video-stream-avi-from-a-series-of-images)

Link related to FFMPEG in .net (From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527963/using-ffmpeg-in-net) question);

[FFMpeg.NET](http://ffmpegdotnet.codeplex.com/)
[FFMpeg-Sharp](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/)
[FFLib.NET](http://www.intuitive.sk/fflib/)
http://ivolo.mit.edu/post/Convert-Audio-Video-to-Any-Format-using-C.aspx

Other resources
[Expression Encoder](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc197144)
[VLC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738228/how-to-stream-your-images-files-with-vlc)

Comment: Thanks for replying,but the first link you specified is for linux right?

Comment: no -> FFmpeg is a complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio and video.

Comment: Can i get a link where it is been implemented using c# ,as i am not able to find one

Comment: i have used FFMpeg (not .NET wrapper) for water marking long back (2-3 yrs back)

Comment: Have you heard about Xuggle,its used by Java Programmers ,is there any way to migrate that to c#

Comment: ok,do u know any other 3rd party tool which can accomplish the same task in c#

Comment: you can check with Expression encoder but it is not free.  http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc197144. I have once used it for video broadcasting (from WEBCAM ) to LAN. It was easy to learn but there was some lag.                      Other option, you can also check with VLC -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738228/how-to-stream-your-images-files-with-vlc

Comment: ok,thanks will check all that and will update the answer to you ,thanks

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Comment: as expected - after many years these links start to go stale i.e. don't work any more - if anyone can find the correct links it might be useful for folk.

Answer (score 7):

I could not manage to get the above example to work. However I did find another library that works amazingly well once. Try via NuGet "accord.extensions.imaging.io", then I wrote the following little function:

```
    private void makeAvi(string imageInputfolderName, string outVideoFileName, float fps = 12.0f, string imgSearchPattern = "*.png")
    {   // reads all images in folder 
        VideoWriter w = new VideoWriter(outVideoFileName, 
            new Accord.Extensions.Size(480, 640), fps, true);
        Accord.Extensions.Imaging.ImageDirectoryReader ir = 
            new ImageDirectoryReader(imageInputfolderName, imgSearchPattern);
        while (ir.Position < ir.Length)
        {
            IImage i = ir.Read();
            w.Write(i);
        }
        w.Close();
    }
```

It reads all images from a folder and makes a video out of them.

If you want to make it nicer you could probably read the image dimensions instead of hard coding, but you got the point.

Comment: How can I increase the length (runtime) of the video?

Comment: Unfortunately `accord.extensions.imaging.io` has been removed from NuGet?!?? Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I bit late but I have made a tutorial on how I solved my similar problem if you did not succeed yet: [Image sequence to video stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744026/image-sequence-to-video-stream/12376324#12376324)

Answer (score 0):

Same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509648/how-can-i-create-an-h-264-encoded-movie-from-a-set-of-images-in-c).

The answer there points to [here](http://jasonjano.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/a-simple-c-wrapper-for-ffmpeg/), which is not exactly what you're doing, but is easily configurable to do the job.

Comment: Hey thanks Ben,Hopefully will solve my problem,will update you once i do that