# Convert WPF Canvas data to video streaming

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, video-streaming

I am just wondering if it is possible to convert WPF Canvas data to video streaming somehow...

Which approaches we can use for it?

I am thinking to generate screenshots and use it to build video frames. Is it correctly?

Any clue?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have some kind of animation in your canvas? How often does the picture refresh?

Comment: Does it always visible? If yes, you could capture video from sceen and clip it to your control

Comment: @dwrd Yup. Canvas has: Video, Images, and other complex User Controls. And it has animations as well. I need to capture WPF Canvas and create video streaming based on it.

Comment: Did you managed to find a solution?

Comment: @Pizzetto No i didnt. try this direction pls https://www.google.com/search?q=wpf+canvas+directx&rlz=1C1GCEU_ruRU819RU819&oq=wpf+canvas+directx&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.9329j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

If You are going to take screenshots and combine it into video, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527914/generating-video-from-a-sequence-of-images-in-c-sharp) will help you

Comment: Thanks! At least my guess is not wrong as I guessed. But I mean if there is some way to streaming WPF Data content in real time mode. Is it possible to do somehow?