# Combine images into a movie

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

My project is to record Desktop as video daily,

now i get to the point of record the desktop as images in `*.jpeg` i need to combine them as video, i don't know much about `ffmpeg` but i have seen [this article](http://fahmifahim.com/2012/10/21/ffmpeg-how-can-i-combine-hundreds-of-images-into-a-movie/), and i wonder if i can make all this as press of a button in C#, so i can combine the images then delete them on the form load or something

EDIT:
now i got the code: `ffmpeg -f image2 -i foo-%03d.jpeg -r 12 -s WxH foo.avi` but i don't know where to type that in my project!

Comment: Similar question [Generating video from a sequence of images in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527914/generating-video-from-a-sequence-of-images-in-c-sharp)

Comment: all i find is just `ffmpeg` code, i can't find where to put it in my project!, i can't just copy and past that: `cd "C:\program files\videolan\vlc" 
vlc -I dummy fake:// --fake-file c:\1.jpg -vvv --sout #transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=1024,scale=1}:duplicate{dst=std{access=udp,mux=ts,dst=localhost:1234}}`

Comment: You won't get a full project here, only guidance and help on specific problematic points