# how to create video stream from images collection and data

Tags: .net, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, aforge

I want to continue my [last question about video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36744334/how-to-create-video-file-from-images-sequence-file)

I want to create video stream from 400 images. 
But on this time i want to add some string ( data ) to the video stream.

I mean that i want to add to each frame some data. 
I know that video can hold a data that can belong to any frame that appear.

How to do it ? 
I looking at [aforgenet](http://www.aforgenet.com/) and i found there only how to create the video stream from images.

I did not found any how to add data ( string ) about any frame.

Comment: Is this text data?

Comment: yes, the data is string .. you can say that its a text

Comment: Do you want to overlay the text on the image?

Comment: no - i want to add data about each frame

Comment: So, save it as side data? Then use subtitles. Use a tool like Aegisub to generate subtitle. Then mux it into a MKV container.

Comment: Mulvya@ - than i did not said this is subtitles. The data is simple text. And the question was how to do the 'mux'

Comment: Yes, but the way to insert the text is in the form of subtitles. You'll have to create a subtitle file, using a tool with Aegisub, then mux it `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i subtitle.srt -c copy -map 0 -map 1 video.mkv`

Comment: ok, and what about the other distraction ? produce image and text from video stream ?

Comment: From images to video is `ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i img%03d.jpg -crf 20 video.mp4`

Comment: WOW. I am currently busy with the same task. Did you found a solution? I am wondering: why you can not attach meta data to EVERY frame of video, which is as "sequence of images", as you can for TIFF file for example?

Comment: still looking for solution. can't use ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

You can use a container format like mkv and add text as subtitle track.

Comment: i can also use mpeg format. but the question is how to do it